# Laravel Auth custom route redirect to /login insted of /(custom path)/login

Tags: redirect, laravel-5.3

I am using Laravel 5.3.29. I want to create a custom route for Authentication.

Here is my web route code.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'hrs'], function(){ Auth::routes(); });
Route::get('/', function () { return view('welcome'); });
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

I made url change to all resources code from /home  to /hrs/home and else.

This is my HomeController code:

```
public function __construct()
{ $this->middleware('auth'); }
public function index()
{ return view('home'); }
```

The problem happens when I hit localhost/home when i am not logged in. It redirects me to localhost/login instead of localhost/hrs/login.
[redirect error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KU2PV.jpg)

where do I have to change to redirect me to localhost/hrs/login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done everything well except one thing. You have not changed into the `Handler.php` file into `app\Exceptions\` directory. Just change into `Handler.php` file into `unauthenticated()` method like this:

> return redirect()->guest('hrs/login');

Full Code:

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest('hrs/login');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This helped me. In custom controller, you can use **protected $redirectTo** property or you should use method **protected function redirectTo()**
In this examples I assumed that you want to redirect to home. You can use routes and views that you want.

Here is my code.

***Example 1:*** Just set property.

```
protected $redirectTo = 'home';
```

***Example 2:*** Use hardcoded path

```
protected function redirectTo(){

    return '/home';

}
```

***Example 3:*** If you have defined routes you can redirect to some route.

```
protected function redirectTo(){

    return route('home');

}
```

[This tutorial](https://laraveldaily.com/redirect-login-register-add-method/)  helped me to solve this problem.